# UITableViewCell's content view has an unexpected margin in buttom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder

Using the latest `Xcode`, and developing for `ios 7`, using a `UITableViewCell`, following the image bellow I see white margin I can't remove by:

1. resizing the content view,
2. moving the grey image. The white margin appears just in the bottom
   and not on top as in picture. There is a work around of using a
   uiview instead of a `UITableViewCell` but I am dead carious to know
   what in `UITableViewCell` is causing the white gap in the bottom.
   Thanks,

[Link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m77kd.png)

Comment: @ArashYou need to set the frame correctly then white color won't come in bottom. You should increase the height by 1.

Comment: @Arashwhat have you tried till now?

Comment: Did you override layoutSubViews and forget to call super? I did this once, with similar results.

Answer (score 0):

Check with this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

The default background color of an UITableViewCell in iOS 7 is white.